# How to get the current ipython session number for use in %history

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

In ipython, the [`%history` magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history) displays the history of the current session. `%history` takes an optional `range` argument that specifies sessions and/or lines to pull the history from. I am wondering how to use `range` specified as `<session_number>/<lines>`, e.g., `%history 243/1-5` which will show lines 1-5 from session 243's history.

1. How can one find the session numbers of past sessions (without merely running through all of them with `%history`) matching a given search string?
2. How can one find the session number of a currently running ipython session?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how to get all the past session numbers without going through all the history. But here is how you get the current and the previous one.

```
>>> ip=get_ipython()
>>> hm =ip.history_manager
>>> hm.get_session_info()
Out: (281, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 21, 9, 13, 51, 939379), None, None, '')
>>> hm.get_last_session_id()
Out: 281
```

Comment: This answer was really helpful. One observation: it seems that the two commands hm.get_session_info() and hm.get_last_session_id() return the same (current) session id.  Regardless these commands got me the answer I needed as I can subtract to get the previous session id.